OSRM error in GC Run instance with osrm data mounted from GC Storage
I have a simple Cloud Run service based on the osrm-backend image: ghcr.io/project-osrm/osrm-backend:v5.27.1 running with the command osrm-routed --algorithm mld /path/to/map/data.osrm.
In the same instance i have mounted some preprocessed osrm map data (a collection of data.osrm.*-files) from a Cloud Storage bucket as described here. I have mounted the data.osrm.*-files at the location used in the instance's command (/path/to/map/data.osrm.*). I have also double checked using ls -l that they in fact are available at this location after mounting with the permissions -rw-rw-rw-.
Now when the Cloud Run service boots it fails after running osrm-routed with the error:
I/O error occurred: /path/to/map/data.osrm.icd : (possible cause: "No such file or directory") (at include/storage/tar.hpp:58)
The error throwing file include/storage/tar.hpp can be found here.
Has anyone experienced something similar?
Please do not hesitate to ask if you need more information about the specific setup.

Cloud Storage volume mounts for services is still in its pre-GA (alpha, beta, infancy) wherein some of its functionalities are still limited and may not work as intended. Please check this link on its limitations as this may affect the performance and functions of your service.

I would suggest filing a bug or a feature request through this link as well.

Thank you for your answer @RobertG! I am considering copying the GCS-mounted files into my service container file system on run and then let osrm access the files directly from the local file system. Does this sound like a viable solution to you?

Also, are the limitations inevitable or might some of the file system compatibility issues be resolved in the future?

You may check this link if your app is fit for Cloud Run. As long as you met all the criteria, your app will be good to go.
